# Considerations for websites delivered using a Citrix client over slow connections

Tags: optimization, web, citrix

I am looking for guidance around creating websites that are delivered using Citrix client and specifically Citrix clients that are on slow connections.

My understanding is that the Citrix ICA client can be described as an intelligent remote desktop connection.

When considering performance for normal web users who will use a website I know I can:

1. Reduce the page weight to ensure less bytes are physically downloaded.
2. Compress images and other static files as much as possible to reduce bytes.
3. Lazy load elements of the page.

My question is will the above improve or affect how quickly the website is delivered over a Citrix connection.

One option I am considering is to allow Citrix users to request a simpler version of the website (akin to maybe text only but a bit nicer!) but I only want to-do this if it will have an affect.

I have developed website used in Citrix many years ago and from my experience then, my answer to the above would be no - however I do-not know if the clients have improved and got better since then.

Answer (score 0):

Point 1 doesn't help the hop from Citrix server to Citrix client. It will help in the sense that it will make the page quicker to load on the Citrix server, but when it is then retransmitted via HDX to the client the speed of getting the page shown on the client is going to be exactly the same.

So #1 is worthwhile, but only in the general sense that you would apply this optimisation for any client of your web page, rather than delivering over Citrix specifically.

Point 2 is somewhat like point 1, so the same comments apply. However re-rendering graphics and sending them down the HDX pipe will certainly affect performance. I would extend this to say: try and reduce the amount (number and size) of graphics you use and also reduce the complexity of images you use (i.e. simpler images are easier to compress). Also minimise changes on your pages, e.g. things like animations will reduce performance.

HDX will do it's own image compression, so anything you do to make your page visually less complex will allow for better compression by HDX.

Point 3: I am not familiar with lazy loading in a web context. If you're not loading visual elements that would otherwise be rendered on the screen, then yes that will certainly help. However if you're talking about loading some background data that doesn't necessarily make the page visually more complex then that won't help.

In simple terms think of HDX as capturing images of your webpage and retransmitting those images. Anything you do to make these "images" less visually complex and more compress-able will improve performance. However retransmitting images is the worst case for HDX. It will try and apply optimisations where it can. E.g. if the app (browser in your case) uses GDI to do rendering then it has a class of optimisations it can apply. We also have some IE specific extensions to make image scrolling in webpages more efficient.

Certainly the protocol has been enhanced and has got better over the years, so you should expect improved performance from what you last saw. Also make sure to experiment with the policies in the XenApp console. There are a number of policies (e.g. for image compression) that you can play with.